# Compare 2 tables with conditions to find results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some assistance in comparing 2 table data's.
One is a table for the items sold, another is a table for the unique code that is sold.
I want to find out the Min and Max Sales and Purchase using The unique Code table to search in the items sold table

Items Sold Table:

```
unique code          qty    unit_price   funit_cost
000-250-0203          1      125.0000     38.4200
000-250-0203         30       20.0000     11.9500
002 250 97 03 ATKC   20       16.0000     13.6000
00-216-1115 L+R      50       45.0000     92.4000
0004635132          200       14.0000      4.2200
002 420 120 20 OPEC   2       48.0000     17.5200
CV TO-4-695 ZUKC      2       48.0000     17.8900
002 250 97 03 ATKC   16       68.0000     68.0000
43512-0K090          28       54.0000     54.0000
69090-0K040           1       10.0000     18.0000
```

Unique Code Table:

```
Unique Code
000-250-0203
000-250-0203 ATKC
0004635132 
00118-27-350 G 
002 250 97 03
002 250 97 03 ATKC
002 420 120 20
002 420 120 20 OPEC
00-214-1914R
00-216-1115 L+R
00-216-1115 L+R ROKC
```

The results need to compare the 2 Tables Data in order to find the Minimum Price as well as the maximum price per Unique Code.

Results need to come out like this For Minimum Price:

```
unique code          qty    unit_price   funit_cost
000-250-0203         30       20.0000     11.9500
002 250 97 03 ATKC   20       16.0000     13.6000
00-216-1115 L+R      50       45.0000     92.4000
0004635132          200       14.0000      4.2200
002 420 120 20 OPEC   2       48.0000     17.5200
CV TO-4-695 ZUKC      2       48.0000     17.8900
43512-0K090          28       54.0000     54.0000
69090-0K040           1       10.0000     18.0000
```

and like this for Maximum Price:

```
unique code          qty    unit_price   funit_cost
000-250-0203          1      125.0000     38.4200
00-216-1115 L+R      50       45.0000     92.4000
0004635132          200       14.0000      4.2200
002 420 120 20 OPEC   2       48.0000     17.5200
CV TO-4-695 ZUKC      2       48.0000     17.8900
002 250 97 03 ATKC   16       68.0000     68.0000
43512-0K090          28       54.0000     54.0000
69090-0K040           1       10.0000     18.0000
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why didn't your attempt(s) work? Please do post your SQL you've written so far by editing your question. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Zafar, nice question. Could you please share what you have tried so far?

Comment: I've tried out both of the answers but none of them have given the requested ouput.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
select us.*
from unitsold us
where us.price = (select max(us2.price) from unitssold us2 where us2.unique_code = us.uniquecode);
```

Or, if you want to guarantee that each row in the second table appears once even if there is no data, then use `outer apply`:

```
select uc.unique_code, us.*
from uniquecodes uc outer apply
     (select top (1) us.*
      from unitssold us
      where us.unique_code = uc.uniquecode
      order by us.price desc
     ) us;
```

Of course, you would flip the sort order or `max()` --> `min()` for the other price.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear, but I understand that you want to obtain the maximum and minimum price of two tables by the unique code.

I understand that what you need is something similar to this.

```
   SELECT
      id,MIN(st.prince),MAX(st.price)
    FROM CODE_TABLE ct
    INNER JOIN SOLD_TABLE st ON ct.id= st.id
```

I hope it helps

Comment: this doesn't produce either of the result sets that the OP has in the question. I'm not going to down vote, but don't be surprised if others do.

Comment: I've tried the code, But it isnt really matching with the same results that i had requested. also there is an issue with the Min price and Max price. it doesnt align with what it should display